# Invoke multiple subnet id's into ec2 instance resource creation in terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, subnet, vpc

I was trying to create two subnets, after that need to invoke these subnets for ec2 instance creation, but getting below error.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "mysubnet" {
  count             = length(var.subnet_cidr)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.myvpc.id
  cidr_block        = element(var.subnet_cidr, count.index)
  availability_zone = element(var.availability_zone, count.index)
}
```

```
resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
  count             = 2
  subnet_id         = "element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*id, count.index)"
  availability_zone = "element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*id, count.index)"
  instance_type     = "t2.micro"
  ami               = element(var.ami_id, count.index)
}
```

```
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*id, count.index)' does not exist
│       status code: 400, request id: e23c77ea-cfd1-4592-8d88-4017cad6fae4
│
│   with aws_instance.myinstance[1],
│   on multi.tf line 36, in resource "aws_instance" "myinstance":
│   36: resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*id, count.index)' does not exist
│       status code: 400, request id: 609ab349-e859-4192-aa4d-ee29e345c283
│
│   with aws_instance.myinstance[0],
│   on multi.tf line 36, in resource "aws_instance" "myinstance":
│   36: resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {
```

how we can use the syntax to invoke the multiple subnets for creating multiple ec2 instances.

Variables.tf.

```
variable "subnet_cidr" {
  type = list(any)

}
variable "availability_zone" {
  type = list(any)

}
```

tfvars file ---->

```
subnet_cidr       = ["10.0.0.0/28", "10.0.0.16/28"]
availability_zone = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b"]
```

Comment: In theory `aws_subnet.mysubnet[count.index].id` should be enough, depending on the number of instances of the subnet resource that gets created. Also, `element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*.id` should be the correct syntax.

Comment: I have used same syntax which you suggested, but still facing the issue.

```
Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidSubnetID.NotFound: The subnet ID 'element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*.id, count.index)' does not exist
│       status code: 400, request id: e5c0a4c5-3f3b-4c99-833e-a8d65d39c5e1
│
│   with aws_instance.myinstance[0],
│   on multi.tf line 36, in resource "aws_instance" "myinstance":
│   36: resource "aws_instance" "myinstance" {

```



Syntax --> subnet_id         = "element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*.id, count.index)"

Comment: Can you add the variable `subnet_cidr` to the question as well?

Comment: This is not interpreted as a function call: `"element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*.id, count.index)"`, it is interpreted as a string. Drop the quotes (`""`) and use it as: `subnet_id         =  element(aws_subnet.mysubnet.*.id, count.index)`. Do the same for  the `availability_zone`.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi

Thanks for your help, it was working fine after dropping the quotes.